# How to disable a message notification in android via program?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Does anyone know how to disable a message notification except from message setting, so the message isn't shown in the status bar ? Thanks.

Comment: Want do you want to do exactly ? Block notifications from another app or cancel a notification your app sent to the notification/status bar ?

Comment: Hope there is no way to disable message notifications on my phone :-)

Comment: The 'Clear' button at the top of the notification  bar?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove notifications you have added, how to disable or clear notifications programmatically, or how to clear or disable notifications from an Android settings menu?

Answer (score 0):

Use `abortBroadcast()` in `onReceive()` of broadcast receiver.